# Read and store page output into another page?

Tags: php, json

I have a PHP page that echos out JSON data based on its GET. Example:

> http://localhost/htdocs/includes/person_get.php?id[]=1&id[]=2

```
[{"id":"1","name_first1":"Daniel","name_last1":"Pendergast"},{"id":"2","name_first1":"Dennis","name_last1":"Pendergast"}]
```

What I want to do is read that from another page and decode into an array. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally extract out the logic that retrieves the person in `person_get` into a function and include that function in both `person_get` and whatever other page needs to use that logic.

If your dead set on calling it you can use `file_get_contents` and `json_decode`

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://localhost/htdocs/includes/person_get.php?id[]=1&id[]=2'));
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2100310/2033671

Comment: Thanks. The reason I split it up like that, is that I also want to be able to access it in Javascript via AJAX. Can you think of a way that would work for both PHP and JS?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery and the jQuery function [$.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) or [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

With jQuery (javascript) you can do something like:

```
$.get(
    'http://localhost/htdocs/includes/person_get.php', 
    { "id[]": [1, 2] }, 
    function( data ) {
        // data is your result array
    }
);
```